# What type of lathe do I need for duplicating parts

Tags: power-tools, tool-selection, turning, lathe

I've worked with a lathe maybe a few dozen times, making things like wooden salad bowls, goblets, baseball bats, and some other relatively simple items.

I'm looking to buy a lathe, and one of the first projects I want to make is a very large chess set (ie: 8" tall king) as a gift to a friend who is an avid chess enthusiast. [I've found some stencils for the pieces I want to make with a lathe](https://www.pennstateind.com/library/CHESSTMP_ins.pdf), but I've only ever used fairly simple lathes. I don't really know what to look for when it comes to a lathe with some sort of modular chisel guide that allows sheet metal stencils to be installed to act as a guide.

What type of lathe should I be looking for if I want to use stencils to create precise replicas of the same part multiple times?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend finding the lathe of your choice.  I personally like my Jet, however there are many great lathes out there.

Then you buy a duplicator for it.  [Rockler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001DT17EK) has a duplicator that fits most standing lathes and will duplicate up to 39" material.

Here is a [Grizzly attachment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000DD1DY) for their lathes.

So as I stated in the beginning.  Find a lathe that meets your requirements (there are many to choose from, with many different options available).  Then worry about your duplicating abilities.  Unless of course you want to buy a dedicated duplicating machine (big bucks).

Comment: I didn't realize the duplicator came as a separate part, so this answer was particularly enlightening. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!